# Empty querySnapshot From the Parent collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone know if there is a way of iterating in the documents of a parent collections ?
I trie to get each documents from my parent collection but the querySnapshot seem to be empty, while it's not the case.

[image: My function log that show a querySnapshot of size equal to 0]

[image: Here my firestore collections]

My collection path look like this :

```
parentCollection(comments)/docs/subCollection(comments)/docs
```

And what i'm trying to do is iterating in each subcollections and their docs and to do that i need to iterate in each documents of the parents collection but when i use get(), it return a empty querySnapshot.

Here my code :

```
return admin.firestore().collection("comments").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    console.log(querySnapshot);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc);
      return doc.ref.collection("comments").get().then((querySnapshot2) => {
        console.log(querySnapshot2);
        querySnapshot2.forEach((doc2) => {
          console.log(doc2.data());
        })
        return true;
      });
    });
    return true;
  });
```

Ps:I know, i shouldn't nested promise.

**UPDATE**

Here what my console.log return when log `querySnapshot.size` and `querySnapshot.empty`:

[image: console.log of my querySnapshot.size & querySnapshot.empty]

here the whole code :

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();


exports.onUpdateUserUpdateComments = functions.firestore
    .document("/users/{userId}")
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
      const userId = context.params.userId;
      const userUpdate = change.after.data();
      const newPhotoUrl = userUpdate.photoUrl;
      console.log("userId",userId);
      console.log("newPhotoUrl",newPhotoUrl);
      return admin.firestore().collection("comments").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log(querySnapshot.size);
        console.log(querySnapshot.empty);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc);
          return doc.ref.collection("comments").get().then((querySnapshot2) => {
            console.log(querySnapshot2);
            querySnapshot2.forEach((doc2) => {
              console.log(doc2.data());
            })
            return true;
          });
        });
        return true;
      });
 });
```

After deploy here the log output

[image]

Comment: Are saying that after this `admin.firestore().collection("comments").get().then((querySnapshot) => {`, the `querySnapshot` has no results? Can you `console.log(querySnapshot.size)` if and update the output of that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes that's it, while my comments collection is not even empty... I notice that, this always occurs when i'm trying to get only the documents of a parent collection which have subcollection.

Comment: There is no known issue that I'm aware of for this situation. It's hard to see what's going on from the code/data you shared so far. Can you try to reproduce the problem in a single Node.js/JavaScript snippet that any of us can run locally?

Comment: I have reproduced it locally. I created same structure in my Firestore and put exactly your code into function and which I just invoked with node and it works properly, Do you have anything in this nested collection? I think the problem might be as well how you run it... Maybe you can add code more codes....

Comment: @vitooh could you show me your code ? maybe it's because i'm missing something, maybe i didn't initialize something..

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes i can, i updated my question...

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this function exactly copy/pasting your code and I can confirm it works perfectly.

I added as well, of course, the structure to my testing firestore:

```
-comments - <genrated docID1> -comments - empty
          - <genrated docID2> -comments - <dummy document>
```

And `users` structure as well to make trigger work. I triggered it by updating 'photoUrl' field manually.

With this structure `querySnapshot.size` gives value `2` and `querySnapshot.empty` is `false`.

Indeed you may find in the logs `QuerySnapshot` with `_size: 0,`, however this is for this nested empty 'comments' collection.

BTW in this code parent collection `QuerySnapshot` is not logged at all. Only documents of parent collection and nested collections.

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

After doing multiple tests, I could see that the problem was due to the fact that even if the documents are visible from the console, they do not exist.
They do not exist because even if they contain a subcollection, they are not counted as data. So that's why the doc is in italic and why the next sentence is display : "**This document does not exist and will not appear in queries or snapshots**"

To solve this, you either have to add data into those docs and remove them if not needed, or you can create them manually in the console.
Or even better, if don't want to change anything in your code, you can use the **listDocuments** method.
The Admin SDK provides a **listDocuments** method with this description:

The document references returned may include references to "missing documents", i.e. document locations that have no document present but which contain subcollections with documents. Attempting to read such a document reference (e.g. via .get() or .onSnapshot()) will return a DocumentSnapshot whose .exists property is false.